# Turning on the flashlight on the Panasonic Toughpad JT-B1

Tags: android, flashlight

I'm currently trying to get the flash of the Panasonic Toughpad JT-B1 to work, but unfortunately with very little success.

The standard example

```
// turning on the flash
Camera cam = Camera.open();
Parameters param = cam.getParameters();
param.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(param);

// turning off the flash
param.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
cam.setParameters(param);
cam.release();
cam = null;
```

isn't working at all, but I don't get any errors or warnings.
I also tried adding `cam.startPreview()` after `cam = Camera.open()` (like suggested in other guides/threads) but the flashlight is staying dark.

I also tried to add:

```
cam.autofocus(new AutoFocusCallback(){
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera cam){
    }
});
```

which only leads to crashing the app as soon as i try to turn on the flash with following error-message:

```
caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: autoFocus failed
```

I'll try further to fix this problem, but if someone knows how i can turn on the flashlight on the Panasonic Toughpad JT-B1 I would be very happy!

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get the flash lighting, with following example, alltough i did some minor changes.

http://code.google.com/p/torch/source/browse/

Comment: Hi julthedroid. The link you put there doesn't work. 
Could you please tell me how did you fix this?

Comment: I found the link finally but could you please add the "minors changes" you made for make this work?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The open source application "SearchLight" made this feature. 
You need to create a SurfaceView to make this work.

Link for the source code:
http://code.google.com/p/search-light/source/browse#git%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fscottmain%2Fandroid%2Fsearchlight